# bash zip file with version read from file and used in zip file name

Tags: bash, sed, zip, jq, command-substitution

I'm able to zip a bunch of files with `zip`

```sh
$ zip build.zip src/*.js src/assets/icons/*.png *.json
updating: src/addReactionsNav.js (deflated 65%)
updating: manifest.json (deflated 55%)
updating: src/assets/icons/icon_128.png (stored 0%)
updating: src/assets/icons/icon_16.png (stored 0%)
updating: src/assets/icons/icon_256.png (deflated 0%)
updating: src/assets/icons/icon_48.png (stored 0%)
```

but I would like to automate it so the name of the zip includes the version. Figured out to do this:

```sh
$ echo "build_$(cat manifest.json | jq .version).zip" | sed s/\"//g
build_1.1.0.zip
```

But can't figure out how to "pipe" the two together.

## Solution

thanks @cyrus

```sh
zip "build_$(jq -r .version manifest.json).zip" src/*.js src/assets/icons/*.png *.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `build.zip` with `"build_$(cat manifest.json | jq -r .version).zip"`.

Update:

Replace `build.zip` with `"build_$(jq -r .version manifest.json).zip"`.

Comment: `cat` is also unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
zip "build_$( jq -r .version manifest.json ).zip" ...
```

---

To include the output of one program in the command line for another, one uses `$(...)`.

```sh
zip "$( echo "build_$( cat manifest.json | jq .version ).zip" | sed s/\"//g )" ...
```

This is the answer to your question, but you can clean this up immensely.

For starters, we can move the dequoting into the inner `$()`.

```sh
zip "$( echo "build_$( cat manifest.json | jq .version | sed s/\"//g ).zip" )" ...
```

`echo "$( ... )"` is effectively just `...`.

```sh
zip "build_$( cat manifest.json | jq .version | sed s/\"//g ).zip" ...
```

Let's get rid of the useless use of `cat`.

```sh
zip "build_$( jq .version manifest.json | sed s/\"//g ).zip" ...
```

Finally, rather than trying to convert the JSON literal into the string it produces using `sed`, we can use `--raw-output` aka `-r`.

```sh
zip "build_$( jq -r .version manifest.json ).zip" ...
```